# how to retrieve VNC viewer stored password on osx

Tags: macos, password-recovery, realvnc, vnc-viewer

I have used Realvnc VNC Viewer on my Mac for enough time to forget my raspberry server password.

The issue is:

- I still can access to the server via VNC Viewer, because the password is stored.
- I have a password for “VNC Viewer password storage” in my Mac Os Keychain, but I don’t have any VNC Viewer password storage application… I guess.
- I have exported my connections but password is encrypted
- I have located ~/.vnc/config.d/vncviewer.d/passwords.json file, but data it is obviusly encrypted.

The question is simple:

How can I access the retrieved pass for my server, or how can I execute VNC Viewer password storage?

Comment: Is it `raspberry`?

Comment: On macos I have VNC Viewer, with which I connect to a raspberry via ssh

Comment: Should be in  `~/.vnc/config.d/vncviewer.d` the files `passwords.json` and `passwords.encmaster` and it should be possible to restore em https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/vnc_password.html

Comment: https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/6661259023389-VNC-Password-storage-in-VNC-Server Legacy VNC passwords are stored in a reversible format. For VNC Server in Service Mode, these are kept in a secure Registry location (Windows) or the home directory of the root user (Mac/Linux). A legacy VNC Viewer is defined as RealVNC VNC Viewer 4.1 or older

Comment: Which version is it?

Comment: VNC Viewer version is 6.19, so not legacy. Nirsoft looks like a good tool but it’s for windows, not mac. If I reach a windows I can try to install VNC Viewer, import connections and then use that tool

Comment: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1397326&sid=977dce564026d578228b7b6a8498f234#p1397326